# How to return the data of datagridview to listbox? c#

Tags: c#

i was trying to get the values of my orders in datagridview and return the data like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uCV8.png)

here's the code of saving to listbox to datagridview.

```
SaveCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Orders", String.Join(", ", listBox1.Items.OfType<string>().ToArray()));
```

and this is the code to preview it on the listbox from datagridview `listBox1.Items.Add(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[8].Value.ToString());`

and it end up displaying like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/snVpg.png) xD

pls help, Thanks in advance!

Comment: you want to show datagridview column (it could be any column) inside a listbox, right?

Comment: yes, something like that, hoping that it can be delete using Lisbox.Items.RemoveAt

Comment: You are joining the string so theoretically upon viewing on Listbox it would show the joined string. Can you provide some more code?

Comment: You want to put those gridView values within listbox and also to delete them?

Comment: yes, & it will be displayed like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uCV8.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This to preview each item inside `dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[8].Value` to `listBox1`

```
dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[8].Value.ToString().Split(',').ToList().ForEach(r => listBox1.Items.Add(r.Trim()));
```

or

```
listBox1.DataSource = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[8].Value.ToString().Split(',').ToList()
```

Comment: @Hexxed Personally I'd recommend splitting those long lines of code into multiple lines to show how the individual pieces work, e.g. one line to get the cell's value, one line to split on `,` and create a list, and another line to all it to `listbox1` :)